# Space groups: Herman-Maugin notation, diagrams and Wyckoff positions

Tags: crystallography

I am currently taking an Introduction to Crystallography course. After studying and understanding the punctual symmetry groups (2mm, 4/m 2/m 2/m, 32,...), the flat groups and the diverse elements of symmetry that exist: helical axes, sliding planes, symmetry planes, among others.

I have doubts when building the diagram of a certain spatial group. For example, in an exercise, I am asked to construct the diagram of the spatial group Pmab.

Pmab implies the existence of:
 an ordinary plane of symmetry perpendicular to the crystallographic axis a,
 a sliding plane of type a perpendicular to the crystallographic axis b,
a sliding plane of type b perpendicular to the crystallographic axis c.

Also, Pmab is an abbreviated notation, because, in reality, there are also two helical binary axes parallel to the axes "a" and "b", and a binary axis parallel to the axis "c".

On the other hand, Pmab belongs to the orthorhombic (rhombic) system and derives from the point symmetry group 2/m 2/m 2/m 2/m.

This is all the information I get from the Herman-Maugin notation. If there is something wrong that I have understood, I hope you will tell me.

Once here I don't know how to start building the diagram, which would look like this:
 [image: http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/057fz1.htm]

As far as Wyckoff positions are concerned, I am often asked for them, but I am not quite sure what they are.

Comment: How do you know that the two binary axes along "a" and "b" are helical?

Comment: I know, because in the orthorhombic system, simplified notation tends to obviate them. But I don't understand why

Comment: That would explain how do you know there are axes in the first place. That's right, but that's not what I asked. How do you know they are _helical_?

Comment: I don't know, I said they're helical, because that's how it appears on the diagram.

Comment: Well, they are helical all right, but you need to know how to deduce that from "Pmab" alone.

Comment: Of course, it's one of the things I'd like to learn. It is fundamental in all of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95676/discussion-between-aprendiendo-a-programar-and-ivan-neretin).

Comment: @IvanNeretin Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, knowing crystallography implies being able to deduce the picture above solely from the group's name $\rm Pmab$, and that's how it is done.

First you write down the symmetry elements mentioned explicitly in the group's name (that is, $\rm m,\;a$, and $\rm b$ in our case; in other examples there could have been axes among them, or even worse) and orient those accordingly, which you already know how to do. Then you **combine** these elements in all possible ways to find out what else is hidden beneath.

Essentially, any symmetry element is but a linear transformation that takes any vector $\bf\vec x$ to another vector $\bf A\vec x+\vec b$, where $\bf A$ is the $3\times3$ **matrix** of our transformation (rotation or reflection or otherwise), and $\bf\vec b$ is the **shift**, that is, a half-translation along the axis for a screw axis, or a half-translation in whatever direction for a glide plane, or $\bf\vec0$ in all other cases. The typical matrices are:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}&
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{Reflection $\perp$ X} & \text{Rotation about X}& \text{Center}
\end{array}
$$

Given two symmetry elements, you simply combine the two transformations by doing some matrix multiplication, which I sincerely recommend, if only to know how it feels. Alternatively, you may rely upon the wisdom of the predecessors, which says:

1. Two perpendicular planes give a twofold axis parallel to both.
2. A plane and a parallel twofold axis give another plane, perpendicular to the plane and parallel to the axis.
3. A plane and a perpendicular twofold axis give a center.
4. Two perpendicular twofold axes give a third axis, perpendicular to both.
5. All of the above remains true if you change

   - every "plane" to "**plane or a glide plane**" and
   - every "axis" to "**axis or a screw axis**".
6. When some of the combined elements have shift in them, the following happens:

   - If the shift is parallel to the resulting element, it **becomes a part** of the said element (that is, the result is going to be a screw axis or a glide plane).
   - If the shift is perpendicular to the resulting element, it **moves** the said element by half the value of the shift (that is, by $1\over4$ of a translation).
7. If you end up with a center of symmetry someplace other than at the origin, you relocate your origin there.

Now try to apply the rules 1-7 and see where this gets you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95724/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-neretin-space-groups-herman-maugin-notation-diagr).