# Pncn space group diagram

Tags: crystallography, group-theory

I'm trying to make a diagram of the Pncn space group.

Firstly, I know that this space group belongs to the orthorhombic system and derives from the point group (2/m 2/m 2/m).

Therefore, although the abbreviated notation does not appear, this spatial group also has binary axes (which may be normal or helical).

We also know that the multiplicity of the space group is 8. That is, there are 8 positions equivalent to (x,y,z). Next, we try to determine them:

1. By the translation of the primitive lattice: (x,y,z)
2. As the point group 2/m 2/m 2/m/m is centrosymmetric: (-x,-y,-z)
3. For the plane type "n" perpendicular to the axis "a": (-x, 1/2+y, 1/2+z)
4. By the plane type "c" perpendicular to the axis "b": (x, -y, 1/2+z)
5. By the plane type "n" perpendicular to the "c" axis: (1/2+x, 1/2+y, -z)

If they were correct, I'd still be missing three positions. These three positions are given by the binary axes. Here I have a serious problem because I don't know if this binary axis is normal ($2$) or helical ($2_1$).

After making these deductions, I check to see if I've done well:
[image]

After that, I realise that some of the equivalent positions do not coincide with those I have deduced. For example, the two of the sliding planes of type "n".

I also have mistakes that I can't explain or understand. These are the following:

a) Why is one of the binaries at 1/4? I've searched the Internet and I can't find any explanation that helps me much.

b) Why is the plane type "n" displaced? I would have placed it on the line of axis "b".

Comment: I thought of adding a link to a [very similar recent question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117638/space-groups-herman-maugin-notation-diagrams-and-wyckoff-positions/117659#117659)... then I realized it was _your_ question. What happened? Are you moving back in time? How can we help?

Comment: Indeed, a month ago I asked that question and you answered it very cordially. The need for the question is that there are still aspects that I do not understand in the realization of these diagrams. It is not a time travel.

Comment: Well, my former answer applies to this problem just as well. How is it different, really?

Comment: The problem is obviously similar. But, I went to solve it to the answer you gave me in your day and I didn't get the right diagram. The seven points you told me to follow are not very well understood and, therefore, I asked this new question. I hope that all of you can help me. @IvanNeretin

Comment: Go by the steps. Draw all the planes. Then deduce all axes and screw axes. Then the center. At each step compare your picture to the known result. Stop when you encounter the first differences. Where are we now?

Comment: But, do I plane when I know it's on the axis or at 1/4? For example, in this case, the plane "n" is 1/4 of the axis and the plane "c" is not. How do I know that?

Comment: When you start, you don't know anything of that. Just put the planes in place (at 0, not 1/4). If the final picture shows some of them at 1/4, this must have been a result of origin shift sometime later. Take a note of that and move on.

Comment: I just drew them on the line of axis a and axis b. I have also drawn them both to 1/2, that is, both planes are cut in the center of the diagram. What do I do next?

Comment: Go for the axes. See if they are positioned _relative to the planes_ the same way they are on the picture.

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: Each axis would be along the intersection of the corresponding planes, unless there is a shift, in which case go for the corresponding step in the instruction and see what the shift does to the axis.

Comment: What means "in which case go for the corresponding step in the instruction"?

Comment: I vaguely remember it tells you what to do when one or both combined elements have shift in them.

Comment: I still don't understand when to set the symmetry elements to 1/4. I would like to know which is the algorithm, set of steps, that you perform to know the diagram.

Comment: You set the axes to 1/4 when **they are** at 1/4. This may result from a few causes: (1) the plane that gave birth to this axis was itself at 1/4, or (2) the plane was at 0, but the other plane contained a shift that moved the axis, or (3) someone shifted the origin afterwards.

Comment: The second reason means that if we have an ordinary plane of symmetry perpendicular to a sliding plane of "tipio b", does the binary axis move to 1/4?

Comment: If the shift is perpendicular to the axis, yes.

Comment: And could you indicate some kind of algorithm that you can use to solve this kind of problems in a correct and efficient way?

Comment: My old answer **is** this algorithm.

Comment: In that algorithm, I find some shortcomings. For example, the 1/4, that we have commented before, and know if the binary is normal or helical.

Comment: The binary is helical if one of the parent planes had a shift along it. Otherwise it is normal. This is not exactly a shortcoming; the answer did actually contain a phrase to that effect _("If the shift is parallel to the resulting element...")_, but you had to decipher it yourself.